# Open Data Cube: Local install of Cube in a Box indexing problems

Tags: open-data-cube

I need to run ODC locally. I am trying to use the [CIAB](https://github.com/opendatacube/cube-in-a-box) and following the instructions in its repo. I have failed a couple of times trying to index the examples.

1. When I first executed the command `docker-compose exec jupyter datacube -v system init`. I have the following warning or error.

   ```
   2021-09-02 06:31:33,948 9 datacube.drivers.driver_cache WARNING Failed to resolve driver datacube.plugins.index::default
   2021-09-02 06:31:33,949 9 datacube.drivers.driver_cache WARNING Error was: ContextualVersionConflict(numpy 1.17.4 (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('numpy>=1.18; extra == "array"'), {'dask'})
   ```

**Is this okay? The prompt was that PostgreSQL was initialized successfully. I assumed that I can continue with the next steps.**

2. I then continued to index from the example using the command `docker-compose exec jupyter bash -c "stac-to-dc --bbox='25,20,35,30' --collections='sentinel-s2-l2a-cogs' --datetime='2020-01-01/2020-03-31'"` and get the following error. It seems that I cannot connect to the product storage?

   ```
   During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/odc/apps/dc_tools/stac_api_to_dc.py", line 158, in stac_api_to_odc
       _ = future.result()
     File "/usr/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 437, in result
       return self.__get_result()
     File "/usr/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 389, in __get_result
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/odc/apps/dc_tools/stac_api_to_dc.py", line 105, in process_item
       meta, uri = item_to_meta_uri(item, rewrite)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/odc/apps/dc_tools/stac_api_to_dc.py", line 88, in item_to_meta_uri
       metadata = item.to_dict()
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pystac/item.py", line 306, in to_dict
       "links": [link.to_dict() for link in links],
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pystac/item.py", line 306, in <listcomp>
       "links": [link.to_dict() for link in links],
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pystac/link.py", line 300, in to_dict
       d: Dict[str, Any] = {"rel": self.rel, "href": self.get_href()}
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pystac/link.py", line 133, in get_href
       if href and is_absolute_href(href) and self.owner and self.owner.get_root():
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pystac/stac_object.py", line 199, in get_root
       root_link.resolve_stac_object()
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pystac/link.py", line 266, in resolve_stac_object
       obj = stac_io.read_stac_object(target_href, root=root)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pystac/stac_io.py", line 226, in read_stac_object
       d = self.read_json(source, *args, **kwargs)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pystac/stac_io.py", line 197, in read_json
       txt = self.read_text(source, *args, **kwargs)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pystac/stac_io.py", line 279, in read_text
       return self.read_text_from_href(href)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pystac/stac_io.py", line 296, in read_text_from_href
       with urlopen(href) as f:
     File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
       return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
     File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
       response = self._open(req, data)
     File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 542, in _open
       result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
     File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
       result = func(*args)
     File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1397, in https_open
       return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
     File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1357, in do_open
       raise URLError(err)
   urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
   ```

**What is causing this? Why can I not successfully index from this storage? I also need to ask some other question. Do I need CIAB or should I install the [core](https://github.com/opendatacube/datacube-core) instead? If I used core, how can I create Jupyter notebooks instances just like in the CIAB?**